# How can I use javascript to make the headings of a table have vertical, angled text?

Tags: javascript, css, css-tables

I am trying to get the names in the heading row of a table run vertically, from the bottom, at a slight angle.

I have tried getting the text to run vertically with:

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.writingMode="vertical-rl";
```

This works in Firefox, but not Chrome
So I have used the following code:

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.transformOrigin = "0% 100%";
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.transform = 'rotate(-80deg)';
```

Which almost works (see image below)

[image]

The problem is that the text is offset by one column (as per the image). So I have tried the following code:

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.left = (displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].offsetLeft + tempp) + 'px';
```

To try and move the text to the right (because tempp is set to the column width)

I have also tried the following code:

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].border="0";
```

To try and remove the border. However, neither of these two lines have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the original code is that the transforms for rotate and translate are separated, when they need to be in a single transform such as:

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.transform = ("rotate(-80deg) translateX(3px) translateY("+temppx+")") ;
```

The reason that the border was not removed is because the .style was missing. It should be :

```
displayTable.rows[i].cells[j].style.border="0";
```